# Attaching global FormType errors to a specific form field in Symfony 2.6

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I was wondiering if it is possible to "drip" global FormType errors instead of 'bubbling' them (which happens by default if you do not set `'error_bubbling' => false` in your FormType option settings).

Here is what I need it for. There is a class-level validator on one of my entites. The validator does some complex checks to make sure that the submitted form data is valid. It needs access to the whole entity object. However, if the validation does not pass, I want to attach the error not only at a global level, but also to one specific field.

I considered creating another, property-level validator, then attaching it to the property in question. This validator should only error out if the global validation does not pass. This is the logic I'm talking about:

```
Entity:
    constraints:
        - GlobalValidator: ~
    properties:            
        property:
            - ValidWhenOtherValid: GlobalValidator
```

However, this does not seem possible in Symofny's form component.

So to ask simple, is it possible to "drip" class-level errors to class' property ('error-dripping' vs 'error-bubbling')?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can validate your object like you do now and afterwards just use `atPath` method like:
`$this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->atPath('foo')
                ->addViolation();`

Example is located there: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator